# Regex pattern to get only the 3-digit numerical value when there is ddd in a line

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get only the 3 digit numerical values if there is ddd in a line,
Here is my input string:

```
here we can also have 370
Hey I have 324 as best value today for 21ddd.
```

In the above string i want to get the 3 digit numerical value if there is ddd in a line, which means i want to get only the 324 as my output.

bellow is the pattern which I tried:

```
price_1 = re.findall(r'\s*\d{3}(?!\s*\d{2}DDD)', line)
```

output:

```
[' 370', ' 324']
```

But the output I need is:

```
['324']
```

can any one tell me the right pattern to get the exact output?

Comment: `(?!\s*\d{2}DDD)` only disallows DDD if it immediately follows two digits immediately after the match and optionally some whitespace. Don't do that if that's not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

If the ddd can be before of after the 3 digits:

```
^(?=.*ddd).*\b(\d{3})\b
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.*ddd)` positive lookahead to assert `ddd`
- `.*\b(\d{3})\b` Match 3 digits in capture **group 1**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X4XgdI/1)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"^(?=.*ddd).*\b(\d{3})\b"
s = ("here we can also have 370\n"
    "Hey I have 324 as best value today for 21ddd.")
print(re.findall(regex, s, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE))
```

Output

```
['324']
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex with a lookahaead:

```sh
(?i)\b\d{3}\b(?=.*ddd)
```

[RegEx Demo](http://(?i)%5Cb%5Cd%7B3%7D%5Cb(?=.*ddd))

**Code:**

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Hey I have 324 as best 123 value today for 21ddd'
>>> print (re.findall(r"(?i)\b\d{3}\b(?=.*ddd)", s))
['324', '123']
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?i)`: Ignore case
- `\b\d{3}\b`: Match 3 digits wrapped with word boundaries
- `(?=.*ddd)`: Lookahead to assert that we have `ddd` (ignore case) ahead

---

If `ddd` may appear anywhere in input then you may use this `python` code without any lookahead but with an `if` condition:

```sh
>>> s = 'Hey I ddd have 324 as best 123 value today'
>>> if 'ddd' in s: print (re.findall(r"(?i)\b\d{3}\b", s))
...
['324', '123']
```

Comment: This requires the DDD to be after the match. Perhaps simplify to `if "ddd" not in s.lower(): continue` and correspondingly remove the lookahead.

Comment: Yes, you are right I assumed `ddd` will appear after 3 digits. I can add `if` but then it won't be pure regex solution

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) like so:

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'\b(\d\d\d)\b.*ddd', line))
# 324
```

`\b` : Word boundary.
`\d` : digit.
`.*` : Any character, repeated 0 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

With PyPi regex module, no need to worry if `ddd` is before or after three digit numbers:

```py
import regex
strings = ["here we can also have 370","Hey I have 324 as best value today for 21ddd.", "123 ddd 454 66666 "]
for string in strings:
     print(regex.findall(r'\b\d{3}\b(?:(?=.*ddd)|(?<=ddd.*\d{3}))', string, regex.S|regex.I))
```

See the [Python proof](https://tio.run/##LU9Nr4IwELzzKya92BpCFNCXGAlXPb@jvEOxq5DwWtLWD/L0t/NAmMvO7G5mdtvOV0YnfV//tsZ6WLrSM3De1vrqkOHEKrKEB@EsNWTjDCp5JyRfKxayA3U4zo04hXQoyXncZXMjeKNkh4uxiNdKqYiFYOs4wcCRblJsR4D9BOPKlIhaz8ztAoxoB@H556roUmslm4bbRVEW6i95FyXPdzzPouXgKV4832dj0PIzFGIRzmbh9Fb0/ZrqUYi@/wc).

**Results**:

```
[]
['324']
['123', '454']
```

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{3}                    digits (0-9) (3 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ddd                      'ddd'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ddd                      'ddd'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d{3}                    digits (0-9) (3 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
```